# Running Today Widgets from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios8-today-widget

While I try to send my Today Extension to iOS 8 device, I face this error many times:
Lost connection to "My iPhone".

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: @HAS Is it not obvious they would be using xcode 6?

Comment: @Popeye Yes, but maybe an earlier beta ... I had tons of those errors in beta 2 or 3.

Comment: @HAS if they are still running on a beta then that is there own stupidity but I think it is safe to assume they are on the release version of xcode 6.

Comment: I'm absolutely with you, but reading the questions here lately shows that quite a few people are still on betas

Comment: @HAS that is their own stupidity then before asking an xcode related question the first thing that should be done as part of your own research is check to make sure you are on the latest release, unless for whatever reason you want to be working on an outdated xcode and even in those super rare occasions I would still say that they should make sure they are on an actual release build not a beta. Beta's are betas for a reason because they still have bugs in them. And based on the OP actually has a respectable rep I would also say they would have thought to be on the latest release before asking

Comment: I'm totally with you there! But that is exactly why I asked that question! ;)